# Can inverse power iteration diverge?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

I'm trying to search an eigenvector based on some eigenvalue approximation. Now I tried to search complex vector for complex eigenvalue. But I've noticed, that under some conditions inverse power iteration does not converge. For example, if I take a real starting vector and the algorithm hits a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues, it will never converge. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes, that is expected. You should be able to identify the invariant sub-space and from that the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

See Krylov-space methods.

If $v_0$ is some unit vector from late in the iteration, $y_0=A^{-1}v_0$ is assumed independent of $v_0$. Remove the $v_0$ contents from it via orthogonal projection and complement and normalize the remainder to get $v_1$. Now
$$
y_0=h_{0,0}v_0+h_{1,0}v_1
$$
Then continue to compute $y_1=A^{-1}v_1$. If the subspace corresponding to the conjugate complex pair has dimension 2, then $y_1$ is a linear combination
$$
y_1=h_{0,1}v_0+h_{1,1}v_1
$$
or at least the remainder after removing the orthogonal projections will be small enough. The matrix $H=\pmatrix{h_{0,0}&h_{0,1}\\h_{1,0}&h_{1,1}}$ now expresses the action of $A^{-1}$ in this subspace, so its eigenvalues will be the conjugate pair of eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$. The inverses of them are then the eigenvalues of $A$ in question.

---

In the case that the reduction of $y_1$ is not small enough, this process continues until some residual does, and $H$ becomes a matrix of Hessenberg structure. As that has usually a much smaller dimension, this reduced eigenvalue problem will be easier to solve. The dimension of $H$ corresponds to the number of eigenvalues with the same smallest absolute value, random influences in $v_0$ can reduce that. Using a shift will separate the radii, thus reducing the dimension of $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as noted by @LutzLehmann divergence is expected. When analyzing matrix algorithms it can be helpful to consider the smallest possible problem where the issue appears. In the present case, we consider an orthogonal real matrix $A$ given by $$A = \begin{bmatrix} c & -s \\ s & c \end{bmatrix}$$ where $$c^2 + s^2 = 1.$$ This matrix represent a counter-clockwise rotation by $\theta$ radians, provided $c = \cos(\theta)$ and $s = \sin(\theta)$. It is straight forward to verify that the eigenvalues are $\lambda = c \pm i s$. Moreover, if, say, $\theta \in (0,\pi)$, then it is immediately clear that inverse power iteration cannot converge for any nonzero initial real vector. Every application of $A^{-1}$ simply rotates the current vector $-\theta$ radians.

In general, there is no reason to believe that issues vanish when we consider large problems. On the contrary, issues tend to grow with the problem size.